# Webpack Config - how can I compiler file in difference path

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have

- `./src` - it's my source files (index.html, index.ts, style.scss)
- `./public` - my site and compiler files (index.html, bundle.js, style.css)

and I wanna build my `./src` files `index.html` into `./public/`, my `index.ts` into `./public/success/script/index.js`, and `style.scss` into `./public/success/style/style.css` for exemple

how can I do that?

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/scripts/index.ts'),
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/'),
        filename: 'app.min.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        static:{
            directory: path.join(__dirname,  './public')
        },
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        hot: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts|.js$/,
                use: ["ts-loader"],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use:[
                    "sass-loader",
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/index.html"),
            inject: "body"
        }),
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`output.filename`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename) configuration, you are allowed to use something like `'js/[name]/bundle.js'` to create a folder structure.

The [`filename`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#filename) of `MiniCssExtractPlugin` works like `output.filename`.

In order to simplify the configuration, the following example does not use `ts-loader` and `sass-loader` as they do not affect the build output.

Project structure(after building):

```
$ tree -L 4 -I node_modules
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── index.html
│   └── success
│       ├── script
│       │   └── index.js
│       └── style
│           └── style.css
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.js
│   └── style.css
└── webpack.config.js
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
import './style.css';

console.log('webpack mini template');
```

`src/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

`src/style.css`:

```css
body {
    background: green;
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/'),
        filename: 'success/script/index.js',
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.html'),
            inject: 'body',
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'success/style/style.css' }),
    ],
};
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset success/script/index.js 3.23 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.html 357 bytes [emitted]
asset success/style/style.css 242 bytes [emitted] (name: main)
Entrypoint main 3.46 KiB = success/style/style.css 242 bytes success/script/index.js 3.23 KiB
orphan modules 2.76 KiB (javascript) 937 bytes (runtime) [orphan] 7 modules
runtime modules 274 bytes 1 module
cacheable modules 111 bytes (javascript) 29 bytes (css/mini-extract)
  ./src/index.js 61 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/style.css 50 bytes [built] [code generated]
  css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/style.css 29 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 203 ms
```

Output:

`public/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
<link href="success/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<script defer src="success/script/index.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
        "webpack": "^5.80.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```